# Rely on `ng-app` in Excel add-ins by AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ms-office, mean-stack, office-js, office-app

I have developing an Excel add-in by `mean-stack`. Long time ago, I saw an answer somewhere about starting up an AngularJS add-in with `office.js` (unfortunately I cannot find the thread anymore). The following solution was suggested, though I don't remember what the initial problem was:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'])
    })
}
```

Now, I try to write `<html ng-app="app">` and NOT use the above block (that allows me to lazy-load `office.js`). So far, it seems the add-in works as well.

So does anyone know if the `<html ng-app="app">` way has any potential risk for an Excel add-in? `Office.initialize` is not mandatory, right?

**Edit 1:** I just realized that it did not work well in all the cases, here is the problem: [Starting up an Excel add-in with ocLazyLoad failed in Excel for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089114/starting-up-an-excel-add-in-with-oclazyload-failed-in-excel-for-windows).

Answer (score 1):

`Office.initialize` is mandatory. The way that I've solved that problem was something like this.

Using [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) configure your mapping of load controller to partial template `loading.html`.

```
$routeProvider.when('/',
{
    templateUrl: 'views/loading.html',
    controller: LoadController
}).when('/app',
{
    templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
    controller: AppController
});;
```

The block so far ensures when you're on the default start of the add-in with `yourserver.org#/` url you're showing the load controller. In the html of your load controller, just put a spinner. So when your app loads, but office.js is not initialized yet, you're showing the spinner.

Now in your `LoadController`you will initialize office.js and redirect to another partial view.

```
function LoadController(/* Your dependencies */){
    Office.initialize = function() {
         window.location.hash = 'app';
    }
}
```

in the `LoadController` where the `'/'` url of the angular app is showing just the loader. So the first template that you see is the loading template - but you're already in the angular app. When office.js initializes, it just points you to the *actual* experience.

Comment: Thank you... Where is `LoadController`? I don't understand your solution, could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if you need more